# How to extract updated XML string from bpmn-js modeler?

Tags: javascript, bpmn, bpmn.io

I am using bpmn-js modeler to render a diagram via XML string as input.

After I make changes to the diagram, then I am trying to console log an updated XML config by doing the following:

```
this.modeler._moddle.toXML(
  this.modeler.get("canvas"),
  {
    format: true
  },
  (err, updatedXML) => {
    console.log("updatedXML", updatedXML);
  }
);
```

And it is logging `undefined`

Comment: Question seems fine, I think. If anyone happens to know this library and happens to have any idea for how to accomplish this task, then they could provide a good answer for myself or anyone else that might need it.

Answer (score 0):

`saveXML` shall get job done.

Try this:

```
// Returns a promise
function getXmlFromModeler(modeler) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    modeler.saveXML(
      {format: true},
      (err, xml) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err) 
        } else {
          resolve(xml)
        }
      }
     )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose you know what a `modeler` is.

The modeler exports a method `saveXML` to turn internal model data into xml:

```js
function saveXML(opts: SaveXMLOptions): Promise<{ xml: string }>

interface SaveXMLOptions {
  format: boolean    // default false
  preamble: boolean  // default true
}
```

- `format`: whether format xml or not
- `preamble`: whether add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n` at the very beginning of the xml.

So, you can export xml like below:

```js
async function exportBpmnXml(modeler) {
  const { xml } = await modeler.saveXML({ format: true })
  return xml
}
```

---

You can get more information in source code:

- https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js/blob/develop/lib/BaseViewer.js#L346
- https://github.com/bpmn-io/moddle-xml/blob/master/lib/write.js#L861

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.